# Connecting MySQL to Dropbox

Tags: php, mysql, dropbox

I've successfully made changes to my httpd.conf file in order to modify the DocumentRoot to my Dropbox folder. No longer does localhost point to /etc/www, but rather /home/Dropbox/www...

This is convenient because no matter which computer I'm on, the changes to my web files are synchronized, and Dropbox keeps a transparent versioning system in the background.

I'm wondering if it is also possible to store mySQL data (not necessarily the actual binaries) in my Dropbox folder. Data synchronization would be equivalently useful if this were possible. What kind of changes would one make to have databases, tables, and other user generated content pushed off to a Dropbox folder, rather than my local hard drive?

Comment: You clearly haven't thought this through properly, or you would have realized that you cannot store the database on a continually synchronized medium. Set up a cron job to dump the sql from time to time, that should do the trick.

Comment: every..single...change... you do will be synced via dropbox. Since the data files are stored as binary, I think this may even make it upload the whole file everytime you update something (I think)

Comment: @JohnP - alright, well if that's the case, this might be a bad idea. For web files, it works great; I don't want to go through git or svn because it's too much overhead for my needs at the moment. For database files...I might be asking for trouble. My web host offers tonnes of MySQL databases, I think my best option is to just connect remotely as @gnur and ahmet have mentioned.

Comment: You can always use a service liks [Backup Box](https://mybackupbox.com) to automatically dump the database to Dropbox without writing any code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is probably easier, and more reliable, to use a remote mysql database. Most web hosts offer mysql services, some even are free. Syncing mysql databases is a pain, no matter how you do it! If you start copying the data files themselves it is just waiting for corruption!

Comment: I have never seen Dropbox corrupt anything before, and using a local database is so much faster

Comment: Even if it isn't file corruption it could become logical corruption, if you just once have the database open on both locations you will be having lots of "conflicting copy of user of file" files which are just an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: I can confirm this can happen, I had my wamp setup really mess up because of some conflicted file copies made which InnoDB engine relied on `ib_logfile0` and `ibdata1` I fixed it by renaming and using the files dropbox had labelled as "conflicted files" to the default files. It's probably better to find a different solution to avoid these issues

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you successfully can copy data folder of MySQL and point it to right there however you may encounter problems with the concurrency. That's not a recommended way. Why don't you use a version control system such as `svn`, `git` with a remote connections allowed MySQL server?

Databases get updated very frequently and dropbox will force it to update too frequently, but it will fail to sync sometimes and your connection will be wasted with DropBox updates. That's really not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, edit your `my.cnf` file and change `datadir` from what is was (perhaps `/var/lib/mysql/`) to `/home/Dropbox/mysql...`

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox cannot handle file ownerships (and permissions), so if your original database file was owned by mysql:mysql, after every sync the owner would be youruser:yourgroup, the permissions set to 664 and the database would be read-only for mysql!

The solution is to add the user mysql to the group yourgroup, and then it works with 664 permissions and you don't have to manually change the ownerships back to mysql every time.